# GPU Compatibility

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

I've recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 but haven't succeeded in getting a driver to work with My graphics card (Radeon Mobility HD 5650).

Is there a graphics card out there I can purchase and add to my system for which there is a confirmed compatible driver?

Note: I'm not a gamer or anything like that; my graphics needs are rather basic.

Answer (score 2):

I have a system using a Radeon HD 5650 (it is the desktop version though), which needs the AMD Catalyst Control Centre to be installed for all the features to work properly. You can download it from here: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English

You might also need the latest proprietary driver installed under System > Administration > Hardware Drivers (Gnome) or System > Hardware Driver (KDE) (alternatively run *jockey-gtk* or *jockey-kde* from command line). My current driver is "ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver".

If you are after some new hardware then you can always check here for compatibility: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport

Comment: As you point out, I'm using the mobility version and I must have tried installing the driver you point to a dozen different ways, to no avail.. Also, are you on 12.10?